# Unneeded space between divs. Can't get rid of it

Tags: css

Here's image displaying my problem

[image]

CSS for wrapper is

```
display: block;
text-align: center;
```

CSS for each DIV is

```
margin: 30px 10px;
display: inline-block;
height: 100%;
text-align: center;
width: 30%;
```

What could be causing this? I tried fiddling with flex but the outcome is the same.

Comment: Provide a jsfiddle or codepen example.

Comment: It looks like you have a layout problem which could have multiple causes. Browser manufacturers are working around the clock to develop a method of inspecting `code`  used to produce the results captured by screenshots but, so far, there has been no significant progress. Meanwhile, do you think you could provide a [mcve] of your problem?

Comment: take a look at column css , and in the future at display:grid ..

Answer (score 0):

You said you fiddled with flexbox. However to make use of it, you should not just fiddle with it, but study how it works.

To achieve what you want, use `display: flex;` on the wrapping div and remove `height` property from your contained `div`s.

Run this visual example to see how it works:

```css
.parent {
  padding: 20px;
  background: red;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
}

.child-1 {
  background: yellow;
  width: 100px;
}

.child-2 {
  background: orange;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child-1">
    Hello
  </div>
  <div class="child-2">
    Multi
    <br>
    Line
    <br>
    Content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think he meant vertical spacing, i guess he looks for a mansory layout :)

Comment: Given the limited info provided in the question, it's hard to see a direct connection between it and your answer. Also, please note you should avoid answering low quality questions. This includes: questions not providing a [mcve] and questions not showing a minimal research effort. See [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and perhaps [this](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) (long, but good).